# Adding dynamic entries to Menu in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, menu, menuitem

I'm trying to dynamically add entries to a JavaFX menu. I have a program that can draw graphs, each time a new graph is drawn, I add an entry to the an `ObservableList` with all graphs.
My `controller` observes the list and on each change, it should modify the `Menu` in the `JavaFX view`. However I'm running in a problem when doing so.
 On the first add, it shows as expected `the first entry`.
 On the second add, the list contains `the first entry + the first entry + the last entry`.
 On the third add it shows the `first entry + the first entry + the second entry + the first entry + the second entry + the last entry`. I guess you can guess the pattern from this point forward.
This code snippet is taken from my controller:

```
graphHandler.getGraphs().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Graph>() {
//GraphHandler.class is my model, that holds the list with all graphs
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends Graph> c) {
        Menu history = graphView.getHistoryMenu();
        history.getItems().removeAll();
        //on change get the Menu from the model and empty it
        String changes = (String) c.toString();
        System.out.println(changes);
        //Output will be added below snippet
        graphHandler.getGraphs().forEach((Graph graph) -> {
            String root = graph.getRootNode().toString();
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem(root);
            //Get the graph's root node name and add a MenuItem with it's name
            item.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            //On choosing a MenuItem load the according graph; works fine
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    graphHandler.getGraphByRootNode(root);
                }
            });
            history.getItems().addAll(item);
            //Add all MenuItems to the Menu
        });
    }
});
```

My approach was to empty the `Menu` on every change and refill it, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have an Idea what I'm missing?

```
{ [com.example.d3project.model.Graph@7eb5106] added at 0 }
{ [com.example.d3project.model.Graph@f510ff2] added at 1 }
{ [com.example.d3project.model.Graph@69239a8d] added at 2 }
```

The output shows what I'm expecting to see. Also the `size()` of the `ObservableList` is as I'm expecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [removeAll(E...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#removeAll-E...-) where you need to pass the objects you want to remove. Since you don't pass any argument nothing will be removed. To clear the list use [clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#clear--) which will remove all items in your history list.

Comment: Once tried to pass `graphHandler.getGraphs()` as argument, didn't work. Thanks for the solution :)