# JavaFX: Dynamically update Menu while showing

Tags: java, listview, javafx, menu, javafx-8

I would like to add a list of options to a JavaFX menu. The order of the options should be modified while the menu is showing (I will use fuzzy matching but the method for that is irrelevant for my issue). I can mimic such a behavior with `CustomMenuItem`s that contain `TextField` and `ListView`, respectively:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MWE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Menu menu = new Menu("MENU");

        final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(
                "AbC",
                "dfjksdljf",
                "skdlfj",
                "stackoverflow");

        final StringProperty currentSelection = new SimpleStringProperty(null);

        final TextField fuzzySearchField = new TextField(null);
        final CustomMenuItem fuzzySearchItem = new CustomMenuItem(fuzzySearchField, false);
        // TODO unfortunately we seem to have to grab focus like this!
        fuzzySearchField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e->{fuzzySearchField.requestFocus(); fuzzySearchField.selectEnd();});
        final ObservableList<String> currentMatches = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        // just some dummy matching here
        fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentMatches.setAll(options.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(newv)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        final ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>(currentMatches);
        lv.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> lv.requestFocus());
        final CustomMenuItem lvItem = new CustomMenuItem(lv, false);
        menu.getItems().setAll(fuzzySearchItem, lvItem);
        fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentSelection.setValue(currentMatches.size() > 0 ? currentMatches.get(0) : null));
        fuzzySearchField.setText("");

        menu.setOnShown(e -> fuzzySearchField.requestFocus());
        final MenuButton button = new MenuButton("menu");
        button.getItems().setAll(menu);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            final Scene scene = new Scene(button);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        });

    }
}
```

However having a `ListView` inside a menu structure feels strange. That's why I tried to use `MenuItem`s instead of the `ListView`:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MWE2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Menu menu = new Menu("MENU");

        final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(
                "AbC",
                "dfjksdljf",
                "skdlfj",
                "stackoverflow");

        final StringProperty currentSelection = new SimpleStringProperty(null);

        final TextField fuzzySearchField = new TextField(null);
        final CustomMenuItem fuzzySearchItem = new CustomMenuItem(fuzzySearchField, false);
        // TODO unfortunately we seem to have to grab focus like this!
        fuzzySearchField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e->{fuzzySearchField.requestFocus(); fuzzySearchField.selectEnd();});
        final ObservableList<String> currentMatches = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        // just some dummy matching here
        fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentMatches.setAll(options.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(newv)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        currentMatches.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>)change -> {
            List<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(fuzzySearchItem);
            currentMatches.stream().map(MenuItem::new).forEach(items::add);
            System.out.println("Updating menu items!");
            menu.getItems().setAll(items);
        });
        fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentSelection.setValue(currentMatches.size() > 0 ? currentMatches.get(0) : null));
        fuzzySearchField.setText("");

        menu.setOnShown(e -> fuzzySearchField.requestFocus());
        final MenuButton button = new MenuButton("menu");
        button.getItems().setAll(menu);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            final Scene scene = new Scene(button);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        });

    }
}
```

In that example, the menu does not get updated while showing, even though I can see `"Updating menu items!"` printed to the console, so the items of `menu` are being updated. The menu on the screen, however, does not change.

Is there a way of requesting a repaint of the menu?

Related questions:

- [JavaFX: Update menu sub-items everytime menu shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983752/javafx-update-menu-sub-items-everytime-menu-shown) The solution seems incorrect, [`Menu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html) does not seem to have a method `setOnMouseEntered`
- [Adding dynamic entries to Menu in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149474/adding-dynamic-entries-to-menu-in-javafx) does not update the menu while it is showing (if I understand correctly)

Comment: I have a very hacky "solution" that I would not like to use as an answer: First, get the private method `Menu.setShowing(boolean)` via reflections. Then, when updating the list and the menu is showing, invoke the method first with `false`, and then with `true` as an argument.

Again, very hacky, not the answer I would like to have, but it works (no idea about any side-effects, though).

Comment: you don't need a reflection, `menu.hide` and `menu.show` will also do.
I can suggest an improvement for your first solution - you can style your `ListView` in a way it looks kinda like a menu (kinda because well, not 100% like a menu)

Comment: Thanks @Enigo
I tried `menu.hide` and `menu.show` but the delay is much longer than going through `Menu.setShowing`. The reasons for that are not entirely clear to me.

I might go with styling the `ListView`. I would expect the menu to be dynamic, even when visible. If that is not the case, I wonder what the rationale behind that is.

Comment: looks like a bug to me: if you do the same directly in a contextMenu (no indirection via a submenu) the list is updating as expected.

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra I just confirmed with my example. Unfortunately, I would rather have `Menu` for my use-case.

Comment: reported [the bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8219620) with a tentative dig into the reason and an outline of a dirty (!) hackaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the suggestions by [@Enigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834206/javafx-dynamically-update-menu-while-showing?noredirect=1#comment96446078_54834206) and [@Jesse_mw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837285/1725687) and used a custom node. Instead of a `ListView`, I decided to go with a `VBox` that contains only `Label`s because I only need basic functionality and do not want to have additional confusing handlers or highlighting. Also note that [@kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra) pointed out, that [dynamic updates of items works out of the box for `ContextMenu` (and a potential bug in `Menu`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834206/javafx-dynamically-update-menu-while-showing?noredirect=1#comment96459728_54834206), which is not an adequate choice for my use-case, unfortunately.

Here is my minimum working example code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MWE extends Application {

    private static Label label(final String text) {
        final Label label = new Label(text);
        label.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> label.requestFocus());
        label.setMaxWidth(200);
        final Background background = label.getBackground();
        label.setOnMouseEntered(e -> label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GRAY.brighter(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY))));
        label.setOnMouseExited(e -> label.setBackground(background));
        // Do something on mouse press; in real world scenario, also hide menu
        label.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            if (e.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                System.out.println(label.getText());
                e.consume();
            }
        });
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Menu menu = new Menu("MENU");

        final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(
                "AbC",
                "dfjksdljf",
                "skdlfj",
                "stackoverflow","ssldkfjsdaf", "sjsdlf", "apple juice", "banana", "mango", "sdlfkjasdlfjsadlfj", "lkjsdflsdfj",
                "stackoverflow","ssldkfjsdaf", "sjsdlf", "apple juice", "banana", "mango", "sdlfkjasdlfjsadlfj", "lkjsdflsdfj",
                "stackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflow","ssldkfjsdaf", "sjsdlf", "apple juice", "banana", "mango", "sdlfkjasdlfjsadlfj", "lkjsdflsdfj");

        final StringProperty currentSelection = new SimpleStringProperty(null);

        final TextField fuzzySearchField = new TextField(null);
        final CustomMenuItem fuzzySearchItem = new CustomMenuItem(fuzzySearchField, false);
        fuzzySearchItem.setDisable(true);
        // TODO unfortunately we seem to have to grab focus like this!
        fuzzySearchField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e->{fuzzySearchField.requestFocus(); fuzzySearchField.selectEnd();});
        final ObservableList<String> currentMatches = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        // just some dummy matching here
        fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentMatches.setAll(options.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(newv)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        final VBox labels = new VBox();
        currentMatches.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) change -> labels.getChildren().setAll(currentMatches.stream().map(MWE::label).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        final CustomMenuItem labelItem = new CustomMenuItem(labels, false);
        menu.getItems().setAll(fuzzySearchItem, labelItem);
        fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentSelection.setValue(currentMatches.size() > 0 ? currentMatches.get(0) : null));
        fuzzySearchField.setText("");

        menu.setOnShown(e -> fuzzySearchField.requestFocus());
        final MenuButton button = new MenuButton("menu");
        button.getItems().setAll(menu);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            final Scene scene = new Scene(button);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: reported [the bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8219620) with a tentative dig into the reason and an outline of a dirty (!) hackaround

Comment: Thanks a ton @kleopatra, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To properly update lists dynamically in JavaFX you can use Binding with an observable list like I did so in your code. The only problem with the following code is it will not work as expected due the functionality of the Menu class, every time the list is updated the menu will hide. I think you should just style a list-view like discussed in the comments, and use the following binding again as it applies to all views that use Observable Lists I believe.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.lang.management.PlatformManagedObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MWE2 extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Menu menu = new Menu("MENU");
    final MenuButton button = new MenuButton("menu");
    final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(
            "AbC",
            "dfjksdljf",
            "skdlfj",
            "stackoverflow");

    final StringProperty currentSelection = new SimpleStringProperty(null);

    final TextField fuzzySearchField = new TextField(null);
    final CustomMenuItem fuzzySearchItem = new CustomMenuItem(fuzzySearchField, false);
    // TODO unfortunately we seem to have to grab focus like this!
    fuzzySearchField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
        fuzzySearchField.requestFocus();
        fuzzySearchField.selectEnd();
    });
    final ObservableList<String> currentMatches = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    // just some dummy matching here
    fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> {

            currentMatches.setAll(options.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(newv)).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    });
   //changed from ArrayList to ObservableArray
    ObservableList<MenuItem> items =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
    currentMatches.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) change -> {
        items.clear();//Clearing items to in-case of duplicates and NULL duplicates.
        items.add(fuzzySearchItem);

        currentMatches.stream().map(MenuItem::new).forEach(items::add);

        System.out.println("Updating menu items!");
        menu.getItems().setAll(items);


    });
    // Binding to Observable items.
    Bindings.bindContent(menu.getItems(), items); 
    fuzzySearchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldv, newv) -> currentSelection.setValue(currentMatches.size() > 0 ? currentMatches.get(0) : null));
    fuzzySearchField.setText("");


    button.getItems().setAll(menu);


    final Scene scene = new Scene(button);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

}